# Is there any way of conecting atoti cube with ActiveUI frontend?

Tags: atoti

We are trying to connect an atoti cube the same way that is on env.js on the Active UI frontend.

```
    window.env = {
  contentServerVersion: "5.11.x",
  contentServerUrl: "https://activepivot-ranch.activeviam.com:5110",
  // WARNING: Changing the keys of activePivotServers will break previously saved widgets and dashboards.
  // If you must do it, then you also need to update each one's serverKey attribute on your content server.
  activePivotServers: {
    // You can connect to as many servers as needed.
    // In practice most projects only need one.
    "Ranch 5.11": {
      url: "https://activepivot-ranch.activeviam.com:5110",
      version: "5.11.1",
    },
    "Ranch 5.10": {
      url: "https://activepivot-ranch.activeviam.com:5100",
      version: "5.10.0",
    },
    "Ranch 5.9": {
      url: "https://activepivot-ranch.activeviam.com:5900",
      version: "5.9.4",
    },
    "my-server": {
      url: "https://localhost:9090",
      version: "5.10.x",
    }
  },
};
```

but when we launch the frontend we are just give this error: 404: The resource at http://localhost:9090/atoti/pivot/rest/v5/ping was not found.

Comment: Which version of atoti are you using?

Comment: Im am ussing atoti 0.7, latest version

Answer (score 1):

The URL in your env.js is probably not correct. You can find the correct one by running the following in your notebook:

```
session.link()
```

Let's call what it returns *my-url*.
Then your env.js should look like this:

```
window.env = {
  contentServerVersion: "5.10",
  contentServerUrl: my-url,
  activePivotServers: {
    "my-server": {
      url: my-url,
      version: "5.10",
    },
  },
};
```

You might also have to change your `version` attribute. It depends on your atoti version, as follows:

- atoti 0.6.x => version = "5.11.0"
- atoti 0.5.x => version = "5.10.0"
- atoti 0.2.x, 0.3.x, 0.4.x => version = "5.9.0"
- earlier => version = "5.8.0"